# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Users#index ? HABTM.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I scaffolded article and user. I get this error message when i am try to retrieve article names on user's index. I think it is saying join table doesn't exist. how to fix this?

error reads:

```
   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Users#index

    PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "articles_users" does not  
       exist
    LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid =   
          '"articles_users"'::regcla...
                                      ^

   :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                 pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
            FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
              ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
           WHERE a.attrelid = '"articles_users"'::regclass
             AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
           ORDER BY a.attnum
```

User table

```
  class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    create_table :users do |t|
     t.string :name
     t.timestamps null: false
    end
   end
  end
```

Article table:

```
    class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
      create_table :articles do |t|
       t.string :article_name
       t.timestamps null: false
      end
     end
    end
```

Join table:

```
   class CreateArticlesUsersJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
     create_table :articles_users_joins do |t|
       t.belongs_to :article, index: true
       t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      end
     end
    end
```

article association:

```
   class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_and_belongs_to_many :users
   end
```

User association:

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
   end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HABTM is using two model names as Join Table by default

On your case, HABTM is using "articles_users" as join table by default

if you want to use another table as Join Table, simply use ":join_table" option

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => "articles_users_joins"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles, :join_table => "articles_users_joins"
end
```

[source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)